# How can I specify network interface for scp?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, scp

I want to transfer a file from a Debian based computer (Asus Tinker Board) to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.

Tinker Board is connected to internet through a [4G/LTE module](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-3g-4glte-base-shield-v2/?attribute_header-type=with%20long%20header) (ppp0 connection), but also has access to the same WiFi network that my laptop is connected to.

How can I copy a file using scp protocol forcing the use of WiFi instead of 4G/LTE, while keeping 4G/LTE connection active?

Comment: Could you add the output of the command `route -n` or `ip r`?

Comment: Simply scp to the IP on the wireless LAN.

Comment: Added output of route -n. scp to the wlan ip gives ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.122 port 22: Connection refused, while the same command to ppp0 ip copies files correctly

Comment: Sounds like the ssh daemon is not listening on all interfaces, or firewall rules are blocking that connection.

Comment: Indeed it was a problem with ssh daemon, once configured simply scp to the wireless IP worked. Thank you.